# Unable to retrieve length of an entity of JSON data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm supposed to read certain data from a JSON file :

[image]

I'm able to print the correct value for :

```
console.log('data1 ' + data.entry[0].id);
console.log('data2 ' + data.entry[0].content.properties.yyn);
```

However, I want to find the length of the properties instead of reading each entity inside properties. I tried:

```
console.log('data2 ' + data.entry[0].content.properties.length);
```

It did not work!

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log('data2 ' + Object.keys(data.entry[0].content.properties).length);
```

Comment: Hi,its still not working with this comment

Comment: @Dodododo Throwing any error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: data.entry[1].content.properties.size is not a function

Comment: That means entry[1] doesn't have content / content.properties . Please check the JSON you are using or share a JSfiddle link with your data

Comment: Thanks Everyone.This was helpful.The error was due to some other piece of code

Answer (score -1):

If you want to know how many keys your object has, use `Object.keys(obj).length`

Answer (score -1):

Properties is an object, not an array. You can count the length of its keys:

```
const numOfProps = Object.keys(data.entry[0].content.properties).length;
```